# How to update widget content after another widget updates same content in qt

Tags: qt, pyside

I have developing desktop application in qt/pyside which is used on multiple computers and it has a common database server.
I have two problems:

1. Problem 1 :When user has a opened widget let's say w1 (e.g widget shows list of cities in database). 
   Now suppose same user opens new widget(w2) (widget which adds/updates city), now if he/she adds new city in database, then how to reflect this change in w1 widget (i.e update content of w1)
2. Problem 2: Scenario is quite similar to problem 1 only difference is when user 1 has a opened widget/tab w1 showing list of cities.
   And user 2 on another machine(but database is same) adds new city then how to update or change user 1's widget (here may possibility that user 1 is working on w1 widget)

Is their any way to do this using some common functionality?

I have figured out 2 solutions for problem 1:

1. Check database changes periodically and update widgets, but it may cause slower the application as there are several widgets.
2. Emit signal from w1 and w2 will have slot to receive signal and then w2 will be updated.

Any other solutions for both problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
case:1
```

connect(w2,SIGNAL(On_Widgetchange),SLOT(this),SignaltoW1anddatabase());

`this` is your parent App. By `On_Widgetchange()` I mean Signal emitted by widget W2 on updating it.
Declare `SignaltoW1anddatabase()` as private a slot.

In Your `SignaltoW1anddatabase()` write code for updating database based on w2 change and also add/remove details to w1 and update w1. This won't slow down your Application.

```
case:2
```

You will be needing to Broadcast a message while updating database, but it is still doable without polling database. Like you can broadcast message containing city name on updating widget on a particular PC to network by using the same Signal Slot mechanism.

```
connect(w1,SIGNAL(On_update()),this,SLOT(sendmessage()));
```

In sendmessage() write code for sending the added detail. And have a netwatcher run on other side.

Comment: Signal emit and connect functionality worked for problem 1, second problem same thing in network not working, what is netwatcher?

Comment: By netwatcher I mean some module constantly probing for incoming packets.